# Multithreading Takes Duplicate Args

Tags: python, multithreading

Alright guys i'm kindda new to python and i thought of making a simple multithreaded script but it doesnt go according to plan. Well what this script does it to take a list of phone numbers and append a number you enter to it and print it , but when you choose the number of threads lets say 3 , in stead of performing the function on two numbers in the list , it performs the function on a each number twice . Can anyone help me to fix this ?

````
from threading import Thread


def test(list):
  i = input('Enter a number: ')
  i = phone[k],i
  print( i , phone[k])

list = ['+4469545444','+15546343565','+145346465343']
threds = int(input('Enter number of threads : '))
phone = []
with open(list) as ph:
for line in list:
   if len(line) > 3:
      phone.append(line.strip())
                
i=0
while True:
   Threads = []
   for k in range(i,i+threds):
    try:
       i+=1
       if(k >= len(phone)):
         break
       th = Thread(target=test,args=[phone[k]])
       th.daemon = True
       th.start()
       Threads.append(th)
    except Exception as e:
       break
   for th  in Threads:
      th.join()
      if(i >= len(phone)):
        break```
````

Comment: Please read  [mre] - it should include an example of the data being operated on. It should **not** include code that retrieves data from an offsite resource or from a file on your computer. In this case I suspect the all that stuff in the middle, `print(Fore...` -> `phone.append...` is superfluous and you should have just included an example of `phone` and left the rest out.

Comment: Anyhow, Welcome to StackOverflow. Help us help you! Your problem can not be recrated as is, because it has wrong indentation. Also why did you import requests? Where is `init` defined? Please read (how to create a minimal reproducible example)[https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example] and fix your code so that we can help you better.

Comment: @wwii  I did what you guys said do you think you could help me now

Comment: @wuerfelfreak can you pls help me now

Comment: @KidBuu You still haven't provided a proper [mcve]. As already explained, the code has multiple indentation errors. You should use four-space indents throughout and make sure the code can be run as a standalone script.

Comment: Just a few of comments: You shouldn't create a variable named `list`; this is a builtin-type whose definition you have just clobbered. You are setting the `daemon` flag on your threads to `True` for absolutely no good reason since you are explicitly waiting for them to terminate with `join`. Your code as presented in uncompilable.

Comment: Using input or the console from threads is subject to race. It should be protected with a lock.

Answer (score 0):

Since I was not able to get your code running, even after you fixed it, I implemented a version myself:

```
from threading import Thread

def phone_append(appendex, numbers):
    for number in numbers:
        print(number+appendex)
    

phone = ['+4469545444','+15546343565','+145346465343','+4469545444','+15546343565','+145346465343','+4469545444','+15546343565','+145346465343','+4469545444','+15546343565','+145346465343']

while True:
    try:
        thread_num = int(input("How many threads?"))
        break
    except Exception:
        print("Not a valid number!")
        
appendex = input("What to append?")

for i in range(thread_num):
    thread = Thread(target=phone_append,args=[appendex, phone[::thread_num]])
    thread.start()
```

Please read [stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) carefully. Try to run, what you post. Make sure, we can actually reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You pass the *current* phone number when you make the thread but you do not use it.  Change the target function to use the phone number that is passed.

```
import threading

def test(ph_no):
    i = input('Enter a number: ')
    print( f'thread:{threading.current_thread().getName()}, original:{ph_no}, adding:{i},  {ph_no}{i}')
```